# How to merge tables in standard sql92 or in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

Suppose I have the following set in a table:

| empid | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 9 |
| 1 | 9 | 10 |
| 1 | 11 | 12 |
| 1 | 12 | 13 |
| 1 | 13 | 14 |
| 1 | 14 | 15 |

I want to have an sql (or an sql process ) that convert the previous set to the following set:

| empid | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 10 |
| 1 | 11 | 15 |

It means that if the end_time of a record equals to the start_time of the next record we shall remove one record and update the record with the new value (of course without touching the main table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, you can use lag to see where an "island" starts, then use a cumulative sum to assign the same number within an island and aggregate:

```
select empid, min(start_time), max(end_time)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_time = start_time then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by empid order by start_time) as island
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_time) over (partition by empid order by start_time) as prev_end_time
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by empid, island;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e92bd75a64f2810e4387628121abbc2f) is a db<>fiddle.